# Link amigável com htacess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Fiz algumas configurações no meu `htacess`. Confira ela:

1. Dentro da minhas pasta `www` tenho uma pasta Sistema e dentro dela tenho uma arquivo chamado `Login.php`. Configurei para sempre que eu digitar `127.0.0.1` o apache sempre chama o arquivo `Login.php`

Segue meu `htacess`:

```
    # Index do sistema
    DirectoryIndex Sistema/Login

    # Configurações do url
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirecionamento do Search
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule (.*) Sistema/$1 [QSA,L]

        # A menos diretório, remover barra final
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://127.0.0.1/Sistema/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Bom o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte.

Para acessar o sistema eu digito: `127.0.0.1/Login.php?nome=HUGO`

Eu queria fazer assim: `127.0.0.1/HUGO`

E dentro do arquivo `Login.php` tenho uma variável que iria receber o nome depois da `/` . Da seguinte forma:

```
 $nome = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nome',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente eu separo o URL em duas partes, a primeira sendo o url do site e a segunda todos os parametros, após isso uso um arquivo de `dispenser`, cuja função é separar os parametros recebidos pelo link e transoforma-los em parametros GET:

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

**dispenser.php**

```
<?php

use LegionLab\Troubadour\Routes\Alias;

/**
 * Resgata parametros da URL, separa controller de method,  pega
 * o padrao do link (site.com/controlador/metodo/parametros). Por fim resgata os demais parametros
 * colocando-o em array para serem usados no controlador.
 *
 * Exemplo:
 * URL -> site.com/pessoas/editar/51
 * Resultado do script será:
 *      $_GET['controller'] = 'pessoas'
 *      $_GET['method'] = 'editar'
 *      $_GET['params'] = array(0 => 51)
 *
 */

$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
unset($_GET['url']);

// verifica se há uma rota
if(!empty($url))
{
    // separa url nas /(barras)
    $params = explode('/', $url);

    // Pega o parametro 0 e 1 para ser minha rota, controller e metodo
    $_GET['controller'] = isset($params[0]) ? $params[0] : '';
    $_GET['method'] = isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : '';

    // Apaga variaveis
    unset($params[1]);
    unset($params[0]);

    // Array para armazenar demais parametros
    $get = array();
    // coloca restante dos parametros no array
    foreach ($params as $value)
        array_push($get, $value);

    // Verifica se há mais parametros e resgata os mesmos
    if(count($_GET) > 2)
    {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key != "controller" and $key != "method")
            {
                array_push($get, $value);
                unset($_GET[$key]);
            }
        }
    }


    // cria um array com os parametros
    $_GET['params'] = $get;
}
```

No caso, como não é dinâmico pode funcionar com:

```
DirectoryIndex login/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ login/index.php?nome=$1
</IfModule>
```

Onde `login/index.php` é o caminho para sua tela de login, que no caso seria: `Sistema/Login.php`

Exemplo:

```
-.htaccess
----login
-------index.php
```

Com essa estrutura de pasta, onde o .htaccess é igual ao anterior, o **index.php** poderia ser:

```
<?php

echo "Olá, ".$_GET['nome'];
```

Ao acessar:

https://dev.local/ht/Overflow (no meu caso)

Seria exibido na tela:

Olá, Overflow

Comment: legal e forma que vc fez, ms no meu caso eu queria fazer de uma forma bem simples. pois isso vai ser usado apenas com o variável nome e na página login

Comment: estava pensando queria alterar apenas a linha `DirectoryIndex Sistema/Login.php?nome=hugo` do htacess. Tem como?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta

Comment: MUITO BOM, OBRIGADO